# Something disables my file & printer sharing settings - how to find out what?

Tags: windows, windows-10, network-shares, file-sharing, windows-firewall

Something happened and I can't access my shared files in LAN.

I check `Private` for `File and Printer Sharing` in `Control Panel\System and Security\Windows Firewall\Allowed apps`, click `OK`,

I select `Turn on file and printer sharing` in `Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network and Sharing Center\Advanced sharing settings -> Private (current profile) -> File and printer sharing`, and click `Save changes`.

after few seconds these settings revert back to unchecked and `Turn off files and printer sharing`.

The odd thing is that if I continuously refresh the firewall settings, it takes about 10 seconds and the "checked" mark is gone.

So something is changing these settings back, how do I find out what is doing it?